# Flappy Bird Genetic Algorithm Population Improvement

Tags: java, algorithm, machine-learning, genetic-algorithm, mutation

I am trying to create a genetic algorithm that learns to play flappy bird.
I have the game working, this is my Bird class:

```
public class Bird extends Player {

public NNetwork network;

public Bird(float x, float y, float velX, float velY, float width, float height) {
    super(x, y, velX, velY, width, height);
    NTopology topo = new NTopology(3,5,1);
    network = new NNetwork(topo, 0.1f, 0.1f, true);
}

public void reset() {
    setAlive(true);
    setX(0f);
    setY(1000f);
    setVelY(0f);
}

/**
 * Feeds the parameters into the neural net
 * @param dyTop height difference to the top edge
 * @param dyBot height difference to the bottom edge
 * @param dx distance to the obstacles
 * @return true if the bird thinks it would be good to jump
 */
public void jump(float dyTop, float dyBot,float dx) {
    network.feed(dyTop, dyBot, dx);
    if(network.getOutputs()[0]>0f) super.flap();
}

public void update(float dyTop, float dyBot, float dx) {
    super.update();
    jump(dyTop, dyBot, dx);
}

public Bird mutate() {
    Bird ret = this;
    ret.network.mutate();
    ret.setAlive(true);
    ret.setScore(0f);
    ret.setX(0);
    ret.setY(1000);
    return ret;
}
```

}

and these are the population mutation functions

```
public ArrayList<Bird> sortBirds(ArrayList<Bird> birds) {
    ArrayList<Bird> ret = birds;
    Collections.sort(ret, new Comparator<Bird>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Bird bird, Bird t1) {
            return bird.getScore() < t1.getScore() ? 1 : -1;
        }
    });
    lastBestScore = ret.get(0).getScore();
    return ret;
}


public ArrayList<Bird> repopulate(ArrayList<Bird> birds) {
    birds = sortBirds(birds);
    Bird bestBird = this.birds.get(0);
    Bird[] retA = new Bird[birds.size()];
    birds.toArray(retA);
    retA[0] = bestBird;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {   //replace the 3 worst birds with mutations of the best one (there are always at least 5 birds)
        retA[retA.length-1-i] = bestBird.mutate();
    }
    ArrayList<Bird> ret = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(retA));
    for(Bird b : ret) {b.reset();}
    generation++;
    return ret;
}
```

the Bird.reset() function just revives the bird and sets it back to the start.
When every bird is dead, repopulate() is called.
In theory, these functions should improve my population over time, but when a bird is better than the others, the next generation is bad again.

Did I misunderstand how genetic algorithms work or is there a bug in the code?
(If you need more code I can post it)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no crossover in your code, which is pretty bad. It usually gives better results.

Secondly, are you keeping only the best genome and 3 of its mutations, and the rest of the population simply gets regenerated from scratch? - that won't work very well, because you need more diversity.

If you want to use mutation alone, I'd suggest to clone the best half into the new generation, and the other half - mutations of the best half. But I'm pretty sure you'll get stuck in a local maximum in this case as well, but it will be much better than how you're doing it.

From my experience with Flappy Bird, you'd be better off starting with constant columns, because it's simpler for the birds to learn and it's easier for you to debug.

Comment: How would I implement a crossover? And what are constant columns?

Comment: @Finni [Crossover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_(genetic_algorithm)) is combining the best genomes' genes to form new children. (Genomes = birds = networks) Genes would be the weights of the neural network you're using. I'd recommend watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeWmdojEJf0) video. Basically, crossover means: Randomly choose 2 parents that have good fitness, and combine their genes, that is, form a new bird, with half of the weights of parent1 and another half of parent2. By constant columns I mean columns (obstacles) at the same height.

Comment: I'll have to disagree with @emil. Crossover, in my experience, never does anything. So I avoid it. But give it a try, see if it works.

Comment: Also, I agree with @emil; it sounds like you're just getting stuck in a minima. Try increasing the mutation rate.

Comment: @Ray I'm not entirely sure If crossover is a bad idea, but [this](http://nn.cs.utexas.edu/downloads/papers/stanley.ec02.pdf) paper would have to disagree a bit.